# Wordpress premalink not working for product page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im new to wordpress , present im working in wordpress-woocommerce project , bascially im confussed with the links , they are not working properly , suppose my project site url is :- [www.cakes-bakery.co.uk](http://www.cakes-bakery.co.uk) and my shop page is [www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes](http://www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes) (this working properly) and i have categories like example round-cakes link is [www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes/round-cakes](http://www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes/round-cakes) (this is also working fine) but each categorie has it own product , for example sample-round-cake-1 link should be [www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes/round-cakes/sample-round-cake-1](http://www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/cakes/round-cakes/sample-round-cake-1) or [www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/round-cakes/sample-round-cake-1](http://www.cakes-bakery.co.uk/round-cakes/sample-round-cake-1) this page is not working , below im attaching image of premalink and product page link , please have a look help me out.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you selected `Shop base with category` for the Product Permalinks?
From the image attached it looks like you can scroll down a little and check what the Permalink is set to

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).